# How to access declared variable from laravel-livewire component in the app layout

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I tried passing a variable from livewire component:

```
class Index extends Component
{
    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.index')->with('type', config('constants.NONAUTH'));
    }
}
```

and accessing it from layouts.app:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">

{{dd($type)}}

@include('includes.head')

...
```

I get an error that `$type` is not defined, what is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: You should make `layouts.app` a livewire component, sinse the component is the child of the `layout.app` it would not have access to any data inside.

Comment: ```layouts.app``` is the default layout which yields the content of the component ```livewire.index```, how do you propose I make it a component in this case? @OzanKurt

Comment: Just make a new Livewire component called `LayoutApp` and return the `layouts.app` view. BUT, my brain is having some hard time now. Then how would you extend your other views to layouts.app...

Comment: I'm sorry my approach probably won't work :(

Comment: It doesn't actually, this is also assuming that  I want to render ```layouts.app``` as a component when in fact it is just a layout - a wrapper. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Let me know if you make it work

Comment: Why pass it when you can just access the config from the master layout?

Comment: Nope, it actually differs for various components; I'm trying to actually include certain styles based on constants from the component.

Comment: You could pass var to js, and onLoad use the var in js. Idk what you want to do with the var exactly.

Answer (score 0):

declare a public variable $type and set this variable inside your mount() function like this:

```
class Index extends Component
{
    public $type = null;
    
    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.index');
    }

    public function mount() 
    {
         $this->type = config('constants.NONAUTH');
    }

}
```

***Edited:***

I see, I got you wrong first time,. I read again and came to understand that the thing you want ,  wont work becuase you are trying to access a variable which is declaring after your app layout. Livewire render its component right after your layout loads. I would recommend you to make your whole app layout using livewire.

Yes there could be various way of declaring something from livewire into your blade. Here is one:

You can fire an event which can be listened by global JS inside your blade.
then you can set that value inside your blade component using jquery / vanilla js.

Comment: I had also tried this prior to asking, it doesn't work.